# Black-out Areas of Video Frame in Python

Tags: python, opencv, video, colors, tracking

Right now I have a script in python that allows me to track a colored ball in a video file. We're testing a robots velocity using a stationary camera, so I only need to track the color over a small span of the video's actual frame area and the rest can be discarded/ignored. Right now, my process is to trim the video trials to only what I need to be tracked, but with 15 trials per test, it becomes very time consuming.

[black out the sides of the video not within the blue lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo4nF.png)

Basically, how would I go about "blacking out" two sides of the video's area so that the color tracking isn't initiated until the robot enters the desired area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your camera is stationary, I'm assuming that the blue taped lines will not be moving in the video frame. With that said, this is the algorithm you follow:

-calculate the approximate region of interest rectangle in your image. You'd need to get the approximate values of- 1. The top left point from where the tracking should begin, say (x,y), and the height and width of the rect to be tracked. Use the image below for reference.[image]

Once you have x,y,w,h, you can extract the portion of the image inside the rectangle as shown:

```
img2=img[x:x+w,y:y+h]
```

You can now run a standard color filter on img2, to track the ball on top of the bot

Comment: This wasn't exactly what I was looking for, but it works very well and just the same. Thank you!